# How to add to string number and keep string in Java?

Tags: java, string

New in programming. How can I add ten to the string number of my age and keep it as string?

What I try:

```
String age = "14";
age + "10";
print(age)
```

It does not work  I want to say it 24.

Comment: You are adding two strings together. You need to convert your age to an integer and add 10 to that (not the string 10 but the integer 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know that the [**String**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) `age` is a valid number (if you don't know it is a valid number you will have to add some code to check for this).

You can simply convert `age` using [**Integer.parseInt**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) then add the **[int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)** `10` and the convert the result back to a String using [**String.valueOf**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-):

```
String age = "14";
age = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(age) + 10);
System.out.println(age); // 24
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert the string value to integer, then add two integer values, and finally convert the result to string like the following:

```
age = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(age) + 10);
```